# Golang быстрее чем С?

Tags: c, golang, инспекция-кода

Решил малость побаловаться и сравнить скорость выполнения Golang и C. Просто интересно было, насколько мой любимый Go уступает Сишке.

Первое, что пришло в голову, это функция переворачивания строки. Написал две абсолютно одинаковые программки: на C и на Go, которые в цикле переворачивают строку 10000001 раз и подсчитывают затраченное время. Ну, и запустил, само собой.

Сказать, что счёт разгромный — это ничего не сказать, но он совершенно противоположен ожидаемому)))

Программа на Go в среднем отрабатывает в три раза БЫСТРЕЕ аналогичной программы на С!!! Не могу в это поверить, может, я просто не умею готовить Си и написал кривой код?

Go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var t time.Time
    var s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    t = time.Now()
    b  := []byte(s)
    for i := 0; i < 10000001; i++ {
        reverse(b)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t).String())
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func reverse(s []byte) {
    var i = 0
    var j = len(s) - 1

    for i < j {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
        i++
        j--
    }
}
```

С:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char s[]);

int main()
{
    time_t start, end;
    char s[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    long i;

    start = time(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 10000001; i++) {
        reverse(s);
    }
    end = time(NULL);

    printf("%f\n", difftime(end, start));
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(s) - 1;
    int tmp;

    for (; i < j;) {
        tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

go version

```
go version go1.9 darwin/amd64
```

cc -v

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
```

Comment: `strlen(s)` - ну конечно, заставляете сишку лишний раз пробегать по строке до конца, а потом жалуетесь, что она медленная. А Go скорее всего хранит длину массива. Потом, на Си можно сделать реверс 8-байтными блоками, подключив команду процессора bswap. Какой тогда будет счет?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Нет, я как-раз таки не жалуюсь, я понять не могу почему так? Всегда был уверен, что быстрее Си только ассемблер, а тут на тебе))) ну а по поводу strlen, это да, но и Go делает тоже самое len(s)

Comment: `len` - скорее всего извлекает готовую длину, `strlen` - бежит по массиву, пока не найдет 0. Попробуйте запомнить результат `strlen` в глобальной переменной, и что получится. Ну и результат `len` тогда уж.

Comment: https://ideone.com/1j9xoY и https://ideone.com/pNyfFa - как видите, тут Go немного проигрывает...

Comment: Ой, забыл, есть еще GCC. На нем тоже можно попробовать. Они с Clang на разных тестах один быстрее другого.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, попробовал, по вашему совету, длину строки посчитать заранее в main, и передавать её вторым аргументом, и в Go и в Си без изменений. Видимо, оба сами кешируют результаты len и strlen. С gcc собирать тоже пробовал, без изменений.

Comment: @Harry Там довольно старая версия Go, возможно из-за этого результат иной.

Comment: У меня получилось Go - 3.56, GCC (-O3) - 3.0, Clang - 2.0.

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь: [Go vs C](https://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64q/compare.php?lang=go&lang2=gcc)

Comment: @AlexanderZonov А версия go какая?

Comment: @ПавелВершинин, у меня всё старье: Go - 1.7.1, GCC - 4.9.2, Clang - 3.5.0.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov И вы код не исправляли? Я вот думаю, что у меня Си шный вариант написан, не оптимально? Я с сишкой маловато общаюсь, к сожалению.

Comment: @ПавелВершинин, исправлял код немножко - посчитал во всех `main` длину строки и сохранил в глобальной переменной.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Не скинете ваш вариант?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**GCC 4.9** (-O3)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char s[]);

int main()
{
    time_t start, end;
    char s[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    long i;

    start = time(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 10000001; i++) {
        reverse(s);
    }
    end = time(NULL);

    printf("%f\n", difftime(end, start));
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = strlen(s) - 1;
    int tmp;

    for (; i < j;) {
        tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

5.000000

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char s[]);

int len;

int main()
{
    time_t start, end;
    char s[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    long i;

    len = strlen(s);

    start = time(NULL);
    for (i = 0; i < 10000001; i++) {
        reverse(s);
    }
    end = time(NULL);

    printf("%f\n", difftime(end, start));
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = len - 1;
    int tmp;

    for (; i < j;) {
        tmp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = tmp;
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

3.000000

**Golang 1.7.1**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var lengt int

func main() {
    var t time.Time
    var s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    lengt = len(s);

    t = time.Now()
    b  := []byte(s)
    for i := 0; i < 10000001; i++ {
        reverse(b)
    }
    fmt.Println(time.Since(t).String())
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func reverse(s []byte) {
    var i = 0
    var j = lengt - 1

    for i < j {
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
        i++
        j--
    }
}
```

3.573949391s

Немного настораживает слишком небольшая разница и нули. `-O3` непредсказуем.

Добавлю вариант, предложенный в комментариях [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp) и мной:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void reverse(char[], int);

int main()
{
    clock_t start, end;
    char s[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    long i;

    int len = strlen(s);

    start = clock();
    for (i = 0; i < 10000001; i++) {
        reverse(s, len);
    }
    end = clock();

    printf("%lf\n", (double)(end-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char s[], int len)
{
    uint64_t *i8 = (uint64_t*) s, *j8 = (uint64_t*)(s+len-8), t8;
    while (i8 <= j8) {
        t8 = __builtin_bswap64(*i8);
        *i8 = __builtin_bswap64(*j8);
        *j8 = t8;
        i8++; j8--;
    }

    char *i1 = (char*)i8, *j1 = ((char*)j8)+7, t1;
    while (i1 < j1) {
        t1 = *i1;
        *i1 = *j1;
        *j1 = t1;
        i1++; j1--;
    }
}
```

1.168988

**Исправлена важная ошибка в коде функции `reverse()` на базе `__builtin_bswap64()`, потому вопрос поднялся в топ.**

Comment: ради интереса замените `int tmp` на `char tmp`, мне интересно, что со временем будет происходить ...

Comment: @Mike, не изменилось. И, думаю, время тут не совсем правильно измеряется, раз целые секунды получаются, но это уже немного другой вопрос. Вот действительно ради интереса можно было бы менять куски строки 8-байтными блоками и использовать для их переворота `bswap`.

Comment: ну вопрос с временем как раз очень важный, я как раз только что это то же заметил, надо все таки миллисекунды брать.

Comment: @Mike, тогда лучше вообще использовать `rdtsc` (измерять в тактах), но как сделать аналог на Golang - вопрос.

Comment: Вот более правильный reverse https://pastebin.com/GqsaqmCd  В варианте ТС оптимизатор C отдельно вел ссылки на байты строки в памяти и отдельно переменные i,j и прибавлял/вычитал 1 из обоих :)

Comment: Вух, у меня с -О3 gcc выдал 1.314800 секунды, уже легче)))
Стал немного быстрее GO 1.96509583 секунды. Но без -O3 как ни верти, 6-7 секунд. 
@Mike да, не знал как в сях с милисекундами посчитать, тут https://ideone.com/1j9xoY добрый человек подправил

Comment: @ПавелВершинин Без -O3 gcc _такое_ генерит, что мне аж плохо. он _все_ переменные ведет на стеке, вместо регистров и постоянно туда-сюда перегружает в регистры, я даже плохо улавливаю что он там делает. примерно 16 (вместо 8) инструкций с двумя очень странными переходами, думаю предсказатель переходов у камня сходит с ума. В принципе -O для того и придуман что бы оптимизировать. А по дефолту он время компиляции сильно экономит

Comment: @Mike Когда был гентушником, вариант lite :), постоянно натыкался на предупреждения, мол никогда не собирайте мир с -O3 ибо с такой оптимизацией поведение системы непредсказуемо. Сейчас это уже не актуально? Можно использовать -O3 в реальной жизни?
P.S. Спасибо, с вашим вариантом reverse, код стал ещё немного шустрее)

Comment: @ПавелВершинин Не знаю когда это было актуально. У меня мир собран с -O3 на нескольких серваках и проблем не замечено.

Comment: @ПавелВершинин Немного поправил по своему разумению ассемблерный код сделанный gcc -O3, выиграл еще порядка 0.08 секунды. Дальше уже практически не куда, разве что как предлагали там в комментах использовать пересылки по 8 байт, что конечно гораздо шустрее (intel вообще не любит 1 байтную работу) с использованием bswap. Но там свои сложности, надо отдельный кусок делать для не выравненных на 8 байт в памяти данных и не кратных 8 байтам хвостам строки. Так что из этого можно заключить что golang так же как и C сгенерил близкий к идеальному код

Comment: @Mike, при пересылке по 8 байт с выравниванием проблема (замедление), а так вполне реально, оставшуюся серединку обрабатываем обычным 1-байтным алгоритмом. Должно быть очень шустро.

Comment: Добавьте, pls, С++ вариант - https://ideone.com/ox12fh - очень интересно сравнить...

Comment: @Harry, а чем замеры на ideone не устраивают? И почему никто до меня вариант с указателями не сделал? :(

Comment: @Qwertiy Да чтоб на одной машине, да с нестарым Go (см. комментарий к моим замерам на ideone).

Answer (score 6):

Во-первых, неправильно использовать `time_t` и `time` для замера времени, поскольку оно уже в секундах. Надо использовать `clock_t` и `clock`.

Во-вторых, чего никто указатели не использует?

Запускаю твою программу на Go на ideone https://ideone.com/An2Ndj и получаю 1.93s.
Запускаю твою же программу на Си https://ideone.com/7N8TTV - получаю 1.73s.
Переделываю на указатели вместо индексов https://ideone.com/yQ2l5J - 1.50s.
И вариант @Harry на плюсах с `std::reverse` https://ideone.com/46PqbD - 1.32s.

А вообще, интересно, что варианты на Си делают ещё один проход по строке, чтобы вычислить её длину. Вариант на плюсах сразу имеет начальный и конечный указатели, а Go, вероятно, хранит длину массива где-то отдельно. Так что в варианте на си надо избавиться от `strlen` внутри функции и явно передавать длину.

```
void reverse(char *str, size_t len)
```

Код из вопроса https://ideone.com/vvwUVs - 2.04s.
Код с указателями https://ideone.com/jtwTeF - 1.38s.

Странно, но в этом случае кода из вопроса незначительно замедлился. Предположу, что это связано с проходом по строке в обратном направлении, при котором возникают сложности с попаданием строки в кэш процессора. Очень странно, что тот же эффект не наблюдается на коде с указателями. В любом случае интересно попробовать пройти только вторую половину строки и посмотреть, что будет.

```
volatile int ignored = strlen(str + len / 2);
```

Вариант из вопроса https://ideone.com/GSqG9i ускоряется до 1.68s.
Вариант с указатеелями https://ideone.com/Tuluoy замедляется до 1.46s.

Замечу, что 1.68 для этого кода - это быстрее обоих вариантов - и варианта с strlen, и варианта без него. А вот 1.46 - это почти 1.50 и получается, что разницы между strlen для всей строки и для её половины правктически нет.

Как видно, Си всё-таки быстрее. А побеждают пока плюсы с их `std::reverse`, но сишный вариант с 1.38 очень близок к этим 1.32 :)

Comment: time не секундами плох, а тем что системное время показывает, которое кушают все процессы, а еще его можно перевести. clock же исключительно время активной деятельности текущего процесса показывает и не учитывает всякое пассивное ожидание. Вместо strlen надо sizeof использовать, будет в compile-time работать, раз уж строка в массиве расположена.

Comment: `uint64_t __builtin_bswap64(uint64_t)` для реверса не пробовали?

Comment: @alexolut, sizeof не будет работать для указателя. Т. е. использовать его можно только в месте объявления массива. А секунды плохи тем, что точности никакой. Начал в 12:34.997, закончил в 12:35.001 - потратил 4ms, а получил 1s. А кто-то начал в 12:35.100, закончил через полсекунды в 12:35.600, а получил 0s. Но ведь второй был медленнее.

Comment: @avp, не понял, как его предлагается использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy понятно, что не будет. Это ж классика из-за неявного преобразования массива до указателя. Просто не надо до этого доводить. И можно не только в месте, смотря как получать к нему доступ. А секунд вполне достаточно, если тест достаточно продолжительный.

Comment: @avp, https://ideone.com/SMO6wf

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, замечу, что `long` олько в линуксе 64-битный. Надо было `long long` писать. А ещё будет важно, выравнено ли значение `(long*)(s+len-8)`. А так да - вроде шустренько: 0.26s.

Comment: @alexolut, так везде же меньше 2s...

Comment: @Qwertiy, OK, длина этой строки 445 символов, то есть указатель (s+len-8) как раз не выровнен на 8 байт. Все равно быстро.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, да. Наверное с `__builtin...` это самый шустрый вариант? Только "для промышленного применения" по идее надо проверять, допустим ли в рабочей системе unaligned доступ к long. Ну, для x86  мы предполагаем, что можно

Comment: Скачал прогу @AlexanderZonov с `__buitin_bswap64` и запустил на i5-2500 в Linux. При компиляции gcc -O3 разница с тривиальным reverse 5 раз (0.33/1.65 sec) (без оптимизации 6 (1.02/6.20))

Comment: @avp, да, он шустрый. Но невыровненные инты - вроде фишка x86, на всех остальных архитектурах оно развалится? Или нет?

Comment: Где как. ARM, начиная с v6 поддерживает, ARC м.б. вкл/выкл. при загрузке, SPARC нет, PowerPC частично (для целых, но не для double), MIPS и Alpha насколько помню есть только для спец. инструкций и т.д.